# Android appcache in android 2.2

Tags: android, mobile, html5-appcache

I'm writing an android app that makes use of WebViews, externally hosted js files, and a manifest file to control appcache. Everything seems to work fine in android 4, but in 2.2 the caching doesn't seem to work.

The flow is as follows:

1. Android app loads and loads a local html file into a webview.
2. Local html files has some javascript to switch the window location to that of a remote 'bootstrap' file.
3. Bootstrap file includes some javascript to download a javascript application and supporting CSS (by writing script/link tags into the dom), and the link to the remote manifest file (absolute URL, served from the same place as the bootstrap file and the application files).
4. Application is downloaded, and renders to the screen.

The manifest file looks like this:

```
CACHE MANIFEST
#2012-04-12

CACHE:
mobile-css.css
app-mobile.js
app.js
bootstrap.html
```

The problem I'm having is that in android 2.2 (HTC desireHD), when I change the manifest file, the app only re-downloads the bootstrap html file, and ignores the app-mobile.js and css files, and always uses the ones in cache. This works how I expected it to in android 4 (changing the manifest file re-downloads all the specified resources).

I've run this in the emulator as well as the device, and the results are the same.

Can anybody see what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to add this line to your webview handling code:
webview.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);

Comment: interesting, thanks.. at the moment i'm "caching" the html/css/js in the APK but will move to this method eventually..

Comment: The path to the cached sources has to be relative to the master page which includes the manifest entry. I don't see the usual `js/` or `css/` in front of the sources. Perhaps that is the Problem?